# How to add html string a Header and footer on Every Page

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I am new to Itext and creating a pdf using a html string. Now I need to add footer and header on every page. I have a html string that i want to add as header and footer.

I gone through many posts and documentation that is in java but that is confusing as no one using html string as footer or header.

**Update Adding code**

Here is the code that I am using. Now I am able to add header and Footer but the html is rendering as string rather then html UI.

```
 public class TestPDF
{
    public static void GeneratePDF(string html)
    {
        try
        {
            Guid random_guid;
            random_guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            string fileName = random_guid.ToString() + ".pdf";
            string filename_with_folder = @"Temp\" + fileName;
            string DEST = System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, filename_with_folder);
            new TestPDF().CreatePdf(DEST, html);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
    public void CreatePdf(String dest, string html)
    {
        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        string header = "Header HTmL HERE";
        Header headerHandler = new Header(header);
        PageXofY footerHandler = new PageXofY(pdf);
        //Assign event-handlers
        pdf.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, headerHandler);
        pdf.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, footerHandler);
        // Initialize document
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(html);
        document.Add(p);
        document.Close();
    }
}
//Header event handler
public class Header : IEventHandler
{
    string header;
    public Header(string header)
    {
        this.header = header;
    }
    public void HandleEvent(Event e)
    {
        //Retrieve document and
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)e;
        PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.GetDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();
        Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
                page.GetLastContentStream(), page.GetResources(), pdf);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
        canvas.SetFontSize(18f);
        //Write text at position
        canvas.ShowTextAligned(header,
                pageSize.GetWidth() / 2,
                pageSize.GetTop() - 30, TextAlignment.CENTER);
    }
}

//Footer handler
public class PageXofY : IEventHandler
{
    public PdfFormXObject placeholder;
    public float side = 20;
    public float x = 300;
    public float y = 25;
    public float space = 4.5f;
    public float descent = 3;
    public PageXofY(PdfDocument pdf)
    {
        placeholder =
                new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0, side, side));
    }
    public void HandleEvent(Event e)
    {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)e;
        PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.GetDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();
        int pageNumber = pdf.GetPageNumber(page);
        Rectangle pageSize = page.GetPageSize();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
                page.GetLastContentStream(), page.GetResources(), pdf);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
        //Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
        //        .Add("Page ").Add(pageNumber.ToString()).Add(" of");
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
                .Add("Footer html will here");
        canvas.ShowTextAligned(p, x, y, TextAlignment.RIGHT);
        pdfCanvas.AddXObject(placeholder, x + space, y - descent);
        pdfCanvas.Release();
    }
    public void writeTotal(PdfDocument pdf)
    {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(placeholder, pdf);
        canvas.ShowTextAligned(pdf.GetNumberOfPages().ToString(),
                0, descent, TextAlignment.LEFT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert in itext here, but I found [this tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers) on it on how to add a header to each page using the c# library.

Essentially you create a event handler class to add the header to the page and set up the pdf object to use that event handler on the appropriate event (page start or page end).  The event handler creates a new canvas object, populates the content it wants to display on the page, positions it, then renders it to the page.  If your header appears to overlap the content at the top or bottom, you probably need to adjust the page margins for the main content to make space for the header and footer.

I am not sure how to place html content into a canvas directly, but since it's not part of the page content anyway, perhaps you can get away with using static content.

**Update by Bruno Lowagie:**

If the header / footer are defined in HTML using `@page` rules, then you just define whatever needs to be in the header / footer in the CSS of your HTML as described in [this tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-2-defining-styles-css).

If the header / footer are somewhat more complex, then you need to create an event handler class. The [jump-start tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-3-using-renderers-and-event-handlers) explains how to add objects such as `Paragraph` to a `Canvas` object. It doesn't cover HTML. However, the [PDF to HTML tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-1-hello-html-pdf) explains how to convert HTML to iText objects (scroll to the bottom of that page for an example).

By combining the different aspects of this answer, you'll be able to solve the problem. If you've tried, and didn't succeed, please show us what you've tried, and we can help you further.

Comment: can we use html tags or can we refer html tags in @page content??

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Now I added code in my post. I am able to add header and footer but now html is not rendring as string with tags in pdf.

Comment: @DalvirSingh you can refer html tags in page content. Have a look at CSS feature called "running elements". It's supported by pdfHTML.